# How can i copy some field value from Applicant to Employee form

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have same fields `Degree` and `tribe` like below

```
        x_tribe = fields.Char(string="Tribe")
        x_degree = fields.Many2one('hr.recruitment.degree', string="Degree")
```

in `Applicant` and `employee` model. I want to copy these field values from `Applicant form` to `Employee form`, when employee is created.

Comment: in side the  employee model make these fields as related

Comment: Can you give me an example please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Related fields.
Example:

```
 partner_id = fields.many2one('res.partner','Partner'),
 participant_nick = fields.Char(string='Nick name',
                           related='partner_id.name')
```

Comment: i am trying code like this  ......    .    x_applicant_id = fields.many2one('hr.applicant','Partner'),
    x_tribe = fields.Char(string='Tribe',related='x_partner_id.x_tribe_applicant') it is giving me an error...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo 8.0-20160225\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Odoo 8.0-20160225\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 1415, in _dispatch_nodb
  File "werkzeug\routing.pyc", line 1433, in match
NotFound: 404: Not Found

Comment: Do these steps: 1.Clear all the cache and history in your browser.

2. keep only one database  for use and remove other databases

Comment: OR Create a new db and reinstall your module and try again

Comment: ok code is running but doing nothing. i am entering data in tribe field of applicant but in employee side tribe field remains empty...

Comment: In your related field replace x_partner_id with x_applicant_id. try below code:
 _columns = {

        'x_applicant_id': fields.many2one('hr.applicant','Partner'),
        
        'x_tribe' : fields.char(string='Tribe', string='Tribe',related='x_applicant_id.x_tribe_applicant')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114583/discussion-between-tahir-noor-and-kbir).